Are there differences in required permissions for changing a value and removing it altogether in firestore?
I'm working with a project (in Flutter) that has a concept of "groups" and I'd like user Alice to be able to add user Bob to their group, change their status, and remove them. For my application, I'd like this to happen both in a document representing the group and on Bob's user document.
For concreteness (initially, before any changes are made):
groups/group1
  - "owner" : "alice"
  - "members" : {}

users/bob
  - "groups": {}

I have security rules set up in Firestore to control who can add people to groups, so only Alice can add people to group1 as they are the owner. This code works (run as Alice):
final batch = FirebaseFirestore.instance.batch();
batch.update(groupRef, {'members.bob': 'member'});
batch.update(bobRef, {'groups.group1': 'member'});
batch.commit();

At this point the documents look like:
groups/group1
  - "owner" : "alice"
  - "members" : {"bob": "member"}

users/bob
  - "groups": {"group1":"member"}

If I then update Bob to be an administrator, that works too:
final batch = FirebaseFirestore.instance.batch();
batch.update(groupRef, {'members.bob': 'admin'}); // changed to admin
batch.update(bobRef, {'groups.group1': 'admin'}); // changed to admin
batch.commit();

Documents:
groups/group1
  - "owner" : "alice"
  - "members" : {"bob": "admin"}

users/bob
  - "groups": {"group1":"admin"}

However, when Alice tries to remove Bob from the group, it fails:
final batch = FirebaseFirestore.instance.batch();
batch.update(groupRef, {'members': {} }); // works individually
batch.update(bobRef, {'groups.group1': FieldValue.delete()}); // fails individually
batch.commit();

The result is:
error: [cloud_firestore/permission-denied] Missing or insufficient permissions.

I'm getting a Firestore permissions error, but I don't understand why, provided that the previous two updates are permitted. Is there a difference in what permissions need to be granted to delete a single field value?
For reference, my firestore rules for Bob's document are like this:
match /users/{name} {
  function allowGroupUpdate() {
        let singleGroup = request.resource.data.groups
              .diff(resource.data.groups).affectedKeys().size() == 1;
        let group = request.resource.data.groups.keys()[0]; // should be only one
        let groupDoc = get(/databases/$(database)/documents/groups/$(group));
        return singleGroup && (isOwner(groupDoc));
      } 

  allow read: if isPublic(resource) || name == request.auth.token.name;
  allow update: if  allowProfileUpdate() || allowGroupUpdate();
  // delete is never allowed for clients
...


Is there something else I need to allow for this action to be permitted?

After messing around with this, it seems like (as far as I can tell) the issue is that the line:
let group = request.resource.data.groups.keys()[0];

appears to fail for FieldValue.delete() calls. I'm not sure why, but it seems like there isn't a key passed to the rules when using that call (very unclear to me why that would be, as I assume the key is still needed to know where to delete).
As you can't extract the keys from the Set produced by something like (there is no getter for all the keys in a set according to the documentation):
let keys = request.resource.data.groups
              .diff(resource.data.groups).affectedKeys();

there is no way to know which group a user is being removed from. To get around this, I changed my client code to update the user to removed -- e.g.:
users/bob
  - "groups": {"group1":"removed"}

and then correctly interpret that when checking what groups a user is a member of. It's a little awkward, but it resolves the issue without adding additional reads / writing to a dummy variable (or similar).
If someone has a better explanation or solution, I'd love to see it.
